# GoogleApps - how can I deploy my application

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I created my first application GoogleApps and I want to deploy it on server. It doesn't work and in logs I found an error:

> Uncaught exception from servlet
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: The
>   index for this query is not ready to serve. See the Datastore Indexes
>   page in the Admin Console. The suggested index for this query is:

```
<datastore-index kind="Greeting" ancestor="true" source="manual">
        <property name="date" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

I suppose that I have to paste this code into my application but I have no idea where. I was following this tutorial:

[Google Apps TUTORIAL - Java](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction.html)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Java app engine, that code needs to go in your `datastore-indexes.xml` file located in your `WEB-INF` directory. The full xml file would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
  <datastore-index kind="Greeting" ancestor="true" source="manual">
        <property name="date" direction="desc"/>
  </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

Comment: After you redeployed with the new file in your application, do you now see the index in the "Indexes" section of the App Engine admin console? If so, make sure the status is "Serving". When you first deploy, it takes a little bit of time before App Engine builds your index (and the time it takes to build increases if there is data in the table).

Comment: I can see 'Greeting' index but status is **Error**. My table was almost empty. So I have to wait? How long?

Comment: No, "Error" is different than "Building". There is something wrong. Is there any more detail in the Admin Logs for your app? You can also try deleting the index from the console and redeploying again. It'll fail (since we haven't corrected the error) but perhaps you can see the source of the error in the eclipse log during the deployment operation.

Comment: My answer showed an XML file. If you're using YAML based configuration, you need to make sure the file is in the yaml format (see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/indexconfig.html).  to remove indexes, remove them from your config file and then run appcfg (see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Deleting_Unused_Indexes).

Comment: Oh, it works! I have no idea why it didn't work...Thanks Cris :)